# draggable bootstrap popup not workin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am making chat application. On second page (home) i have list with users. When i click on user i want to open popup window. I am using this code for popup.

http://jsfiddle.net/dave_wilton/a3gyq/5/light/

But when i click on some user instead of showing popup am redirected on first page Login.

Here is my code:

**home-controller.js**

```
 (function () {

    'use strict';
    function HomeController($scope,redirectService) {

        $scope.homeController = {};

        $scope.homeController.users = [
            {
                icon: 'img/online.png',
                name: 'Vanessa Angel'
            },
            {
                icon: 'img/online.png',
                name: 'Tom Baker'
            }
        ];

        $scope.homeController.logOut = function () {
            redirectService.loginToLogin();
        };
    }


    angular.module('chatApp').controller('homeController', HomeController);
})();
```

**home.tpl.html**

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="right">
        <input type="submit" id="logOut" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign Out" ng-click="homeController.logOut()">
    </div>
    <div class="left clear">
        <h1 style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'"><b>Online users</b></h1>

        <div ng-repeat="user in homeController.users">
            <user-directive user-list="user"></user-directive>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**user-directiv.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('chatApp').directive('userDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                userList: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'src/home/user.tpl.html'
        };
    });
})();
```

**directive tmpl**

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <p class="item">
                <a href="#myModal" data-backdrop="false" data-toggle="modal">
                    <img width="20px" height="20px" ng-src="{{userList.icon}}"/><span class="icon-text">{{userList.name}}</span>
                </a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Settings</h4>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Settings</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
</div>
```

**redirect service**

/**
 * Created by user on 15.09.2015.
 */

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('chatApp').factory('redirectService', function ($state) {
        var service = {};
        service.loginToHome = function () {
            $state.go('home');
        };

        service.loginToLogin = function(){
            $state.go('login');
        };
        return service;
    });
})();
```

**EDIT added app.js for config states**

```
(function () {

    'use strict';
    angular.module('chatApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
        .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

            $stateProvider
                .state('login', {
                    url: '/login',
                    templateUrl: 'src/user/login/login.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'loginController'
                })
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/home',
                    templateUrl: 'src/home/home.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'homeController'

                })
        });
})();
```

Comment: Can you add the code for declaring states in app.config?

Comment: @user3727843 i added the code

Comment: okay so i added data-target='#myModal' and changed href="#" but know when i click on user nothing happens...

Comment: dont have the href at all

Comment: @user3727843 it doesn't working. When i click on user nothing happens....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90072/discussion-between-bukic-and-user3727843).

Answer (score 0):

So you are using some url routing service (most likely angular-ui router) and you have an anchor tag with `href='#myModal'` which using the twitter bootstrap (as im assuming you are/that fiddle is) would, in combination with the data-toggle, bring up your modal.

However, because you are using angular-ui router, the router is likely trying to read the `href='#myModal'` as a state (i.e. /myModal or /home.myModal) except that it isn't a valid state so it is redirecting to /login or whatever you have set your `$urlRouteProvider.otherwise` to.

You can fix this using `data-target='#myModal'` as opposed to the `href` tag